# How to switch byte order of binary data

Tags: python, struct, pack

I have a binary file which I'm reading where some 2 byte values are stored in 'reverse' byte order (little endian?), eg.

```
1D 00 13 00 27  00 3B 00 45  00 31 00 4F
```

The original program that created these values stores them internally as shorts. Those values should correspond to: 29, 19, 39, 59, 69, 49, 79. I'm trying to read these values using python 2.6.5 (although this will probably be run on much older systems, eg 2.3 and 2.4).

I've tried using

```
val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7 = struct.unpack("1h 1h 1h 1h 1h 1h 1h", data)
```

and, of course, the values all come out wrong:

```
7427
4864
9984
15104
17664
12544
20224
```

After looking at the documentation for struct, I thought I'd be able to use something like

```
val1, ... = struct.unpack("!h !h ...
```

but when testing, I only got

```
struct.error: bad char in struct format
```

How can I unpack these values with the correct byte ordering? Am I stuck reading in the two bytes separately then reassembling them in the python code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Byte order is specified with a single character, at the beginning of the format string.

```
values = struct.unpack('!7h', data)
```

Comment: Aha, that was it. I have several format specifiers in the format string but only placed the byte order char in front of the 'h' specifier instead of at the start of the whole string. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

How about

`>>> a='\x1d\x00\x13\x00\x27\x00\x3b\x00\x45\x00\x31\x00\x4f\x00'`

`>>> struct.unpack('<%dH' % (len(a) / 2), a)`

`(29, 19, 39, 59, 69, 49, 79)`?

According to the [struct](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) documentation it looks like you need to use `<` to specify little-endian.

Comment: Addition of `struct` reference is nice. BTW, `>` for `big-endian`

Answer (score 1):

I have solved a similar problem of reversed byte order by using `a.byteswap(True)`, but I am not sure if this is the most efficient method.